# Changing file content using sed in bash

Tags: bash, sed, while-loop

I have a problem with changing file content using sed. Let me describe what I would like to do.

I have a few text files in one folder:

> 123.txt
>
> 456.txt
>
> 789.txt

If you open them, each of those text files will have such a text at the top line:

> Blablabla

What I would like to do is using **while** and **sed** commands to replace Blablabla with the file name without extension and that's how I wanted to do it:

```
for files in ./*.txt; do
    while ! [[ $(grep "${files%.*}" ./"${files##*/}") ]]; do
        table_name="${files%.*}"
        sed -i 's/Blablabla/$table_name/g' ./"${files##*/}"
    done    
done
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.  Could anyone help me with that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: BashFAQ #21, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021, covers the topic in detail -- including (in accordance with best practices) suggesting tools that are more portable than `sed -i` (a non-POSIX extension).

Comment: Why do you need `while` loop inside `for` loop?

Comment: What about your attempt doesn't work? What is that `grep` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @anubhava: My code has a bug and sometimes **sed** doesn't work so using **while** I want to repeat loop until it's done.

Comment: @ Etan Reisner: I wanted to use **grep** to check if the text inside of the file was already changed or not